# How to consume typing indicator from twilio chat channel via webhook

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex, twilio-node, twilioflexwebchat

I'm using twilio chat service to integrate my inhouse chat platform with twilio flex. when creating the channel via the node SDK, I register a webhook to to consume messages sent over the channel and pass them on to our chat clients.

Does the flex chat widget for agents sends a typing indicator?

Are the typing indicator messages consumable via the webhook integration?

Answer (score 1):

I think typing indicator is enabled default in flex UI and can not sent over Webhooks.

Please check this [Flex](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.21.0/MessageList.html)

Also there is few links for typing indicator. [Js code document](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/typing-indicator)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Typing indicator messages are not sent over webhooks, only through [the Chat SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/sdk-download-install).

Sohail is also correct that the Flex UI will send typing indicator messages that can be consumed from the Chat SDK on the user side (for example, the [Flex Web Chat UI can use the typing indicator](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-webchat-ui/2.9.1/MessageList.html)).